# How to add a subView to all UITable Cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift4, swift4.2

Without using storyboard.

I'm trying to add an error label to any cell where a value is not filled out/saved. I concluded that I dont need to show this logic and the issue is showing more than one error labels in all/more than one tableView's cell.

I've created this viewLabel to reuse:

```
struct Label {
    static let errorLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 18, height: 18)
        label.text = "!"
        label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.height / 2
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.font = UIFont(name: "CircularStd-Black", size: 14)
        label.clipsToBounds = true
        return label
    }()
}
```

**Inside cellForRowAt:**

```
// I'm using detailTextLabel
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
cell.addSubview(Label.errorLabel)
// [...] constraints for Label.errorLabel
return cell
```

Based on this example, I'd expect to show a red circle on all cells but instead, it shows on the last cell. Why?

Comment: Please add your full CellForRow function, you are probably reusing in the wrong way, or not reusing at all (;

Comment: Thanks. I have updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things wrong here:

1. You should only add to cell contentView. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623229-contentview)

*Example:*

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(myLabel)
```

2. Better reuse would be to add your, label once.
   This can be done in interface builder or init or awakeFromNib. This way reuse will be more efficient.
3. **And this is the main issue you are seeing**:

You are adding **one** static label, again and again.

Meaning: only the last cell will display it because there is only one label (:

Better use a function to create the label (Factory function)

```
static func createLabel() -> UILabel {
  let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 18, height: 18)
        label.text = "!"
        label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.height / 2
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.font = UIFont(name: "CircularStd-Black", size: 14)
        label.clipsToBounds = true
        return label
}
```

Comment: So basically I cannot use a `Struct`? 

Comment: @Sylar function can still exist inside a struct (:

Comment: Excellent! I shall refactor and use a custom cell class. But as is, it works well.

Comment: @Sylar is there a reason you want to use a struct? UILabel is a subclass anyway so there is pretty much no reason to use a struct. By adding the label there you are losing all the advantages of value types. Just a suggestion, use a class instead.

Comment: What do you mean, sorry? the errorLabel gets replaced `detailTextLabel` based on `x`

Comment: @Sylar Not really talking about functionality. Whenever you use a struct you do it to have a value type, inmutable and which you can copy to create another instance, right? But what happens if now you add a reference type inside a value type? It is now mutable and holds a reference, it can cause leaks etc etc. For me a rule of thumb is that a struct should contain only value types, arrays, cgfloat, dicts, etc etc. If you are going to put a reference type inside a value type, well, do everything in reference type since the beginning, you will need to mutate anyway. Hope this makes a bit of sens